# How to compare scipy noise filters?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, filtering, noise-reduction

I need to reduce my noise like behavior in my data. I tried one of the method called [*Savitzky-Golay Filter*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter) . On the other hand, I need to find fastest method, because the filtering algorithm will be in the most running script in my code.

I am not familiar with the signal processing methods. Can you suggest faster methods and usage of them briefly?

I do not need complex structure like low-pass, high-pass etc (I know there are thousands of them). As fast as possible smoothening method is what I want to use.

Here my test script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

noisyData=np.array([
   2.77741650e+43,   1.30016392e+42,   8.05792443e+42,   1.74277713e+43,
   2.33814198e+43,   6.75553976e+42,   2.56642073e+43,   4.71467220e+43,
   4.25047666e+43,   3.07095152e+43,   7.30694187e+43,   7.54411548e+43,
   1.29555422e+43,   8.09272000e+42,   9.18193162e+43,   2.25447063e+44,
   3.43044832e+41,   7.02901256e+43,   2.54438379e+43,   8.72303015e+43,
   7.80333557e+42,   7.55039871e+43,   7.70164773e+43,   4.38740319e+43,
   8.43139041e+43,   6.12168640e+43,   5.64352020e+43,   3.63824769e+42,
   2.35296604e+43,   4.66272666e+43,   5.03660902e+44,   1.65071897e+44,
   2.81055925e+44,   1.46401444e+44,   5.44407940e+43,   4.50672710e+43,
   1.60833084e+44,   1.68038069e+44,   1.08588606e+44,   7.00867980e+43])

xAxis=np.arange(len(noisyData))

# ------------- Savitzky-Golay Filter ---------------------
windowLength = len(xAxis) - 5 
polyOrder = 6

from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

# Function
def set_SavgolFilter(noisyData,windowLength,polyOrder):
    return savgol_filter(noisyData, windowLength, polyOrder)

plt.plot(xAxis,noisyData,alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xAxis,set_SavgolFilter(noisyData,windowLength,polyOrder))

# ------------- Time Comparison ----------------------
import time
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(50):
    savgolfilter1 = set_SavgolFilter(noisyData,windowLength,polyOrder)
print(" %s seconds " % (time.time() - start_time))

# === OTHER METHODS WILL BE HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really need polynomial-based smoothing, Savitzky-Golay does not have any particular advantages. It's basically a bad lowpass filter. For more details, see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5888646

Using a basic Butterworth lowpass filter instead:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
b, a = butter(5, .2)
datafilt = filtfilt(b, a, noisyData)
```

The `filtfilt` call seems to be several times faster than `savgol_filter`. How much faster do you need? Using `lfilter` from scipy is at least 10 times faster, but the result will be delayed with respect to the input signal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That script is what I want to. Noise removing will be in the bottleneck of my code, so I need as fast as possible. Phase shifted cancellation which is `lfilter` does not work for me, because I will take numerical integral, `simps`,of this data. It might cause a problem.

Comment: Ok, good to hear. One thing to consider is that integration itself tends to reduce noise, so if you only use the data for integration, filtering it beforehand might not make much difference.

Comment: Yes, you are right. *filtering it beforehand might not make much difference*, this is the main thing for me. If the data fluctuate rapidly like noisy behavior, numerical integration methods require smaller bins to reduce error. It reduces my code speed. Due to the fact that, I will smoothen my data for increasing integration bins. At the end, as you said, result of integration will not change dramatically.